# Rate-limiting the data sent down WebSockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

We're sending a lot of data down a websocket (from a Node.js app to the web browser).

The data is binary data in the form of `blobs`.

Occasionally, the end-user is on a poor connection - and in this case, we'd like to 'skip' messages (leave them out) and make sure we don't cram down more data than the user can receive.

On the server side, we have tried:

```
function sendBlob(blob, socket) {
  console.log('socket.bufferedAmount: ' + socket.bufferedAmount); // Always zero

  if (socket.bufferedAmount > 0) {
    return; // Never called
  }

  socket.send(blob);
}
```

Unfortunately `bufferedAmount` always returns zero.

Is this the right way to see how much data is being queued but not sent/received in websockets, or is there a better way to achieve this?

(Have also tried logging `socket.bufferedAmount` on the client-side, but it also always returns zero).

Comment: Which server-side websocket server are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/einaros/ws (version 0.4.30). Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `socket.bufferedAmount` property that exists on clients (as well as the [ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws/) module for Node) is the amount of bytes that it itself has buffered, not the remote. That means `socket.bufferedAmount` on the server means how many bytes that are waiting to be sent to the client, and for the client it is how many bytes are waiting to be sent to the server.

The reason you aren't getting any change in the property is that your network is probably indeed sufficient to deliver the data. If you actually want to see a difference in `socket.bufferedAmount`, then try throttling your browser network access. This can be done with browser extensions or tools like [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/).

If you want to throttle connections by skipping messages, you can think about creating some type of heartbeat system between the client and server. There are many ways you could do this, such as applying this function:

```
setInterval(function() {
  if (socket.bufferedAmount == 0) {
    socket.send('heartbeat');
  }
}, 1000);
```

And then detecting missed heartbeats by counting the time interval. This is rather inefficient, but there's also other ways to do this such as responding to sent data from the server (although take into consideration that if you want to send a heartbeat when receiving data, the heartbeat itself might get throttled or other side effects).

An alternative solution would also be available if you were willing to switch to [Socket.IO](http://socket.io). It has a feature that allows you to send volatile messages, which are messages that are dropped if the client is busy or is not able to accept messages for any reason.

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var timer = setInterval(function () {
    socket.volatile.emit('data', 'payload');
  }, 100);

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
  });
});
```

Do note that Socket.IO will be heavier on your application, and doesn't use the native websocket protocol. It will utilize websockets when it is an option, but it is one of many transports. Socket.IO is built on Engine.IO, which uses a fork of the module you're currently using.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! We were using Socket IO but need to send binary data now, thus switching to native WebSockets. I've been testing with Network Link Conditioner on my Mac, and while the connection is obviously a lot slower, `bufferedAmount` on the server-side seems stays at zero.

Comment: You would have to limit the connection of the server, not the client, for the server's `bufferedAmount` to increase.

Comment: Ahh .. I see. So is there any way to tell if the *client* is on a slow connection, when most of the data is going from server to client?

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't, which is where the client heartbeats I outlined in the post can work. The client will not send a heartbeat for that interval if the `bufferedAmount` is greater than zero.

Answer (score 1):

The readonly attribute `bufferedAmount` represents the number of bytes of UTF-8 text that have been queued using `send()` method.

And your case here shows that you are trying to access it on message received from server.
so the `bufferedAmount` is not set.

Comment: What's the best way to achieve the desired outcome, do you think?

Comment: u may impose some condition on e.data.length

Comment: Rather than just limit the amount of data, I need to assess if the data is getting 'stuck' and modify how much data I'm sending dynamically. I'm okay to set up a PID controller (or similar). I just need to figure out what metric to track that increases on a slow connection.